# Update code on both Git and the Linux server

Tags: git, github, pycharm, phpstorm, workflow

Bit of a newbie confusion between my friend and myself when it comes to code editing workflow.

At the moment we use "Browse remote host" option in PyCharm to edit the code on the Linux server where we have multiple Python and PHP files. We were wondering if implement the Git and GitHub solution what would be the best workflow?

Pull the code from the GitHub to the PyCharm on our PC, edit the code, push the new code back to the GitHub and then pull that code on the Linux server to see applied changes?

Or, use the "Browse remote host" option to directly edit files on the Linux server, and when the files are edited and tested, we push those changed to the GitHub?

What would you suggest based on your experience, or based on the best practice?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The remote server should always and absolutely always only run the code. It cannot be a development machine!

Best practice is to use CI/CD concepts, which means you should write the code on your machine and push it to remote repository, setup some pipeline in a few stages to lint, test your code and build/deploy it on remote host.

Again, if you don't want the hustle of setting up the pipeline, you and your friend should always write the code on your machines, and push it to github (or any other remote scm system) and then pull and run the code on linux server. It is because both of you will always now what the other one is doing or has done.

If you're using remote server as a development machine you will quickly get in a large mess.